# Combine a packed header and numpy array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

Does anybody have any tips on how to pack a header and then append it to some chunk of data?

For example, if I have a bit-packed header of 16 bytes, and then I want to append it to a raw RGB image of about 2MB, what is the most efficient way of doing this?

So far, I've tried the following

```
headerVals = ( str(headerVersion), str(formatEnum), frameCount, ntpTimestamp, width, height )
packedHdr = self.imgStruct.pack( *headerVals )

return packedHdr + data
```

However this fails with the following error because str and numpy arrays arent concat'able:

```
    return packedHdr + data
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'numpy.ndarray' objects
```

The only way around this that I can think of, as a Python beginner, is the following which is extraordinarily slow for obvious reasons:

```
# Generate the header
headerVals = ( str(headerVersion), str(formatEnum), frameCount, ntpTimestamp, width, height )

packDir = 'cchqhh{0}h'.format(width*height*3)

return pack( packDir, str(headerVersion), str(formatEnum), frameCount, ntpTimestamp, width, height, *data )
```

Any ideas? As a Python initiate I find myself a little stumped by this!

UPDATE:

As per seth's suggestion below, I updated my code to the following, and it is working nicely.

```
# Generate the header
headerVals = ( str(headerVersion), str(formatEnum), frameCount, ntpTimestamp, width, height )
packedHdr = self.imgStruct.pack( *headerVals )

# Concatanate header to the data
return numpy.concatenate( ( numpy.fromstring( packedHdr, dtype=numpy.uint8 ), data ), axis=0 )
```

Comment: Why not put `headerVersion` and `formatEnum` inside a numpy array, then try to concat?

Comment: I ended up taking this approach and it seems to be working. Adding changes to question

Comment: okay, I'll put my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate your header with the numpy array you'll need to have the array in binary form. Assuming `data` is an array of ints:

```
import struct

raw_data = packedHdr + struct.pack('i' * data.size, *data)
```

If your data is of a different kind, you need to specify it in `st.pack`. You can then unpack the resulting `raw_data` in the desired form.

Comment: So this works, but I think the efficiency is not great because data is blitted into data.size ints behind the scenes, right?

Comment: @bgoldber this will indeed double your data in memory, but it should be put in the same data type as the original numpy array (otherwise you are packing data representations in wrong formats!). For a 2Mb image this is really trivial and the performance issues should be minor, unless you are doing this a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put `headerVersion` and `formatEnum` inside a numpy array, then try to concat?